# remove empty rows to the bottom

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to remove empty rows to the bottom. When I use the way below, I have a problem with the formulas in the table.

Make a new column to the right. Use the formula =IF(C2<>"",2,1) and fill down.
Hide the column from prying eyes (just right-click on the grey column header at top to hide it)
Sort by this column instead of C.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: show an example of desired behavior and of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

It will delete and empty rows when there are empty cells in `column c`

Code

```
Sub g()

 Dim r As Range
 Dim rng As Range

   For Each r In Range("C1:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
      If r = "" Then
         If Not rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Union(rng, r) Else Set rng = r
      End If
   Next r
    rng.EntireRow.Copy
    Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    rng.EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I don't want to delate rows. I need just remove blank rows to bottom.

Comment: I tried your code and there is one error, when I ran it. Debugger indicated this row: (rng.EntireRow.Copy). Excuse me, but I'm the beginner.

Comment: @M.R. You are only going through `column c`?

Comment: I try your code again in another table and it work! This is what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: @M.R. , you are very welcome. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

if column D is empty you could try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    With Range("C1", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        .Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
        .Offset(, 1).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not exactly what I need. This macros clear contents in column D and remove it in column C. :)

Comment: The macro leaves in column C the not blank values only and clears column D as it uses it just as a "helper" column. If you want to clear column C and have not blank values in column D then the changes are simple, but I see you already have an accepted answer so you're done with it